# Are Embraced Ghouls blood bonded to their Sires?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

A vampire wants to embrace a ghoul (which is, of course, blood-bonded to the vampire).

Once the embrace takes place, what happens?

- The new childe is *still* fully blood-bonded to his new sire?
- The new childe is simply 1/3 blood-bonded to his new sire?
- Aside the blood sympathy, there is no initial blood bond between the two?
- Something else?

I'm interested by viewpoints, as well as references (books, pages, etc.)

*(I never found those answers in the new WoD rulebooks)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Ghouls**, page 87, "Embracing Your Ghoul"

> Finally, once the ghoul is Embraced, he retains any blood addiction and Vinculums he possessed as a ghoul.

Comment: It should be noted that the text from *Ghouls* seems to be overriding the core book, which states that the all-consuming power of the Embrace destroys all blood addictions and blood bonds. My group generally runs with the idea that the most-recently-published book takes precedence, but it's something to consider.